# Prove the covariance matrix can be obtained from the quadratic form of a pdf that has the same form as a Gaussian function

Tags: probability

From chapter 2 in "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Bishop", a multivariate Gaussian pdf is defined as,
$$
N(x | \mu, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{0.5D}} \frac{1}{|\Sigma|^{0.5}} \exp\big(-0.5(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \big) \space \space (1)
$$

In section 2.3.1, he proved a pdf has the form of a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), with C and D are constant,
$$p(x) = C\exp(-0.5(x-b)^TS^{-1}(x-b) + D) \space \space (2)$$

and then concluded the pdf is Gaussian pdf with $S$ as the covariance matrix.

Why can the author be sure that without checking the constant C and D, (2) can be arranged to have the form as (1), and so it is a Gaussian pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of any probability density function $\ p\ $ over the whole of its domain must be $1$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}p(x)dx=1\ .
$$
So if $\ p(x)=kf(x)\ $, where $\ k\ $ is constant,then we must have
\begin{align}
1&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}p(x)dx\\
&=k\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx\ ,
\end{align}
and therefore $\ k=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx\right)^{-1}\ $.  In particular, if
\begin{align}
p(x)&=Ce^{-\frac{(x-b)^TS^{-1}(x-b)}{2}+D}\\
&=Ce^De^{-\frac{(x-b)^TS^{-1}(x-b)}{2}}\  
\end{align}
where $\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $, then
\begin{align}
Ce^D&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\frac{(x-b)^TS^{-1}(x-b)}{2}}dx\right)^{-1}\\
&=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\det(S)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ ,
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The portion inside the brackets of the $\exp(\cdot)$ is just a quadratic. In one dimension, the portion from (2) is $-(x-b)^2/2S + D$ which can be factorised by difference of squares into $-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma$ to match (1). In multiple dimensions it’s a little more involved, with diagonalisation of $S^{-1}$, but it’s the same principle.

Geometrically, the equivalence of (2) with (1) is a change of coordinates: the origin of the coordinate system is moved to the mean of the Gaussian, and the coordinates are then rotated so that the axes align with the principal components of the Gaussian.